# Huion H420 pen going in inverse direction

Tags: animation

I recently got a Huion H420 drawing tablet.

So I booted it up, installed the driver and started to test it out.

But what I found surprised me, when I was testing on Sketch.io, my pen moved in the opposite direction of my hand, don't know why.

Comment: Tablet is upside down?